# How to export Exchange public folder permissions and import them to a different system?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, powershell, public-folders, exchange-2013

I'm involved in a migration from Exchange 2010 to Office 365 (Exchange 2013); all user mailboxes have already been successfully migrated, but due to some glitch or bug that even Microsoft's support was unable to explain and/or fix, the [standard public folder migration procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj983799%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) completely refused to work. In a pinch, we resorted to exporting all PFs to a PST file and importing it in the new system.

This went ok; all PFs are now online and accessible.

However, we completely lost all client permissions in the process; there are about 300 PFs, thus reconfiguring them by hand would be quite a heavy task.

The user accounts have been synchronized between Active Directory and Office 365, so the same user names and group names exist in both systems.

**Is there any way to export all public folder client permissions and apply them to an identical public folder hierarchy, where the same user names and group names are present... but in a completely different Exchange environment?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get-PublicFolderClientPermission and Get-PublicFolderAdministrativePermission will give you the permissions; Set-PublicFolder*Permission will let you apply them to the new hierarchy. Persisting the permissions is left as an exercise for the reader :)